# Visualizing a sort algorithm

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I want to visualize a sort-algorithm. To do that, I wrote such programs by using jQuery and Canvas, but it doesn't work.

```js
function Draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 1500, 1000);
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  for (var k = 0; k < l; k++) {
    context.fillRect(1000 * k / l, 0, 1000 / l, resarray[k] * 1000 / l);
  }
  context.fill();
}

Bubblesort = function() {
  var flag = 1;
  while (flag) {
    flag = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < l - 1; j++) {
      if (resarray[j] > resarray[j + 1]) {
        var tmp = resarray[j + 1];
        resarray[j + 1] = resarray[j];
        resarray[j] = tmp;
        var dfd = new $.Deferred;
        setTimeout(function() {
          Draw();
          dfd.resolve();
        }, 2);
        dfd.then(flag++);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`resarray` is the Array I want to sort. `Bubblesort()` is the function to do bubble sort. `Draw()` is the function to display the present arrays values.

With each swap I want to smoothly show the change of value in `resarray`. To applicate to other programs, I don't want to use break. How should I write the code?

Comment: I want the programs to swap resarray 1time by 2ms.

Comment: I don't know if you want to code it by yourself to learn or just look at how a sort work. For the second case, you can take a look at this site : https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms/